# How to create a EFI partition using PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, diskpart, table-partitioning

I would like to automate a script that creates an EFI partition.

Currently, one step is manual and requires to start DISKPART and execute these commands:

```
create partition efi size=100 
format fs=fat32 quick label=SYSTEM 
assign letter=S
```

How can I get the same result using PowerShell? I haven't seen any option in the
New-Partition cmdlet to create an EFI partition.

Comment: You should be able to use `-GptType '{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}'`.  If that doesn't work, you can create it as another partition type and use Set-Partition with GptType.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect this would be the equivalent in [PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/new-partition?view=win10-ps):

```
New-Partition -DiskNumber 0 -Size 100MB -GptType "{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}" -DriveLetter "S"
Format-Volume -FileSystem FAT32 -NewFileSystemLabel "SYSTEM" -DriveLetter "S" -Force
```

Modify as appropriate to suit your use-case.

Comment: Can you, please, verify it works? I'm getting "Invalid GPT type" errors in for the New-Partition command. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, the GPT type is taken directly from the MSDN docs, you may need to reformat the disk first and make sure it's selecting the right disk?

Comment: I did exactly that. Unfortunately, it refuses to work: Invalid GPT Type. However, the The GUID is OK according to the docs.

Comment: Try `Initialize-Disk -Number 0 -PartitionStyle GPT` and make sure the disk is not Read-only

Comment: The disk is already inialized. I cannot Initialize-Disk again since I would lose every partition and I don't want that :)

Comment: `Get-Disk` and verify it is GPT..?

Comment: Change size to "512MB", and perhaps the information here incl. the comments may help - https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/05/29/use-powershell-to-initialize-raw-disks-and-to-partition-and-format-volumes/

Comment: Also @GregAskew mentioned if it doesn't work you may be able to create it as another partition type, then use `Set-Partition` - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/set-partition?view=win10-ps

Comment: I've used "Set-Partion" to change the GptType, but it always tell me "the specified partition type is invalid".

Comment: Set-Partition -PartitionNumber 43 -DiskNumber 4 -GptType c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b
Set-Partition : The specified partition type is not valid.

Comment: OK, I've finally got it! you have to indicate the guid like this:
Set-Partition -PartitionNumber 43 -DiskNumber 4 -GptType "{c12a7328-f81f-11d2-ba4b-00a0c93ec93b}"

Comment: Hahaha oh gosh, I'm sorry. Thanks for updating my answer

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you need to select a disk before you can create a partition.

Read `diskpart /?`, use :

> ```
> Microsoft DiskPart syntax:
>         diskpart [/s <script>] [/?]
>
>         /s <script> - Use a DiskPart script.
>         /?          - Show this help screen.
> ```

Note that *a DiskPart script* is simple plain text file where the diskpart commands are placed in (one command per line), for instance `MyDiskpart.txt` listed below.

```
diskpart /s MyDiskpart.txt
```

**Answer**: The latter command you can run from an elevated  `powershell` session as well as from an elevated  `cmd` session (˙diskpart˙ always requires elevation).

**Addendum**:

Moreover, `Diskpart` accepts input from a [pipe ('|') as well as from `<` redirection](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) so that the following `cmd` commands are equivalent:

```
diskpart /s MyDiskpart.txt
diskpart<MyDiskpart.txt
type MyDiskpart.txt|diskpart
```

The latter commands tested using the following *diskpart script*:

```
==> type MyDiskpart.txt
list disk
list volume
select disk 1
list partition
```

Moreover, you need not to create a *diskpart script file*; the following `.bat` script displays system volume details (selecting *volume #* dynamically):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions

:check_permissions
echo Administrative permissions required. Detecting permissions...
net session >nul 2>&1
if %errorLevel% == 0 (
    echo Success: Administrative permissions confirmed.
) else (
    echo Failure: Current permissions inadequate.
    goto :endlocal
)

:do_the_job
for /f "tokens=2" %%a in ('echo list volume ^| diskpart ^| findstr System') do (
    (
        echo select volume %%a
        echo detail volume
    ) | diskpart
)
echo DONE
:endlocal
pause
```